# CNAME pointing to domain instead of subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, cname-record

I have a SAAS application which has 3 different subdomains.

```
example.com 
app.example.com
support.example.com
```

I want to White Label the services only in `support.example.com`

Example: `testcompany.com` requires services to my `support.example.com`

To achieve this, I need something like `support.testcompany.com` which should basically load the `support.example.com` website.

I have created a CNAME record in `testcompany.com` DNS, pointing to `support.example.com`

But `example.com` is being loaded instead of `support.example.com`

How do I solve this? Is this the right way or is there any other approach?

Answer (score 1):

A DNS CNAME record only points a hostname to the same *server* that the target  hostname points to.

It does not automatically configure the web server to load the same websites for both hostnames. That takes additional reconfiguration of the web server software, i.e. Apache, Nginx

(You circumvent that issue somewhat by designating  one website the **default VirtualHost** that will always get displayed when  unknown hostnames are used to access the web server, but that only works for plain http, not so much for https)

Comment: `example.com` renders `<p>Website</p>` and  `support.example.com` renders `<p>Support Website</p>`. Both are includes in sepearte `index.html` files, I have my Apache server configured to handle the subdomains. But the CNAME record pointing from `support.testcompany.com` is rendering `example.com` content instead of `support.example.com` content.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether you use an `A` record pointing to the same IP address or a `CNAME` record pointing to another hostname that eventually points to the IP address. The browser will always send a `Host:` HTTP header containing the hostname in its address bar.

Therefore, your `VirtualHost` for `support.example.com` needs an alias for the other hostnames, e.g. `support.example.net` and `support.example.org`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName support.example.com
    ServerAlias support.example.net support.example.org
    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

Otherwise, the webserver will show the default virtual host, which in this case seems to be `example.com`.

It might also be a good idea to have a default catch-all virtual host to prevent every hostname pointing to that IP address from showing the contents for `example.com`. Your current configuration might affect SEO and it could have security issues, too.